# Orders do not exist in Magento 2 but customer payments successfully captured with assigned order numbers

Tags: paypal, magento2, magento-2.3, amazon-pay, adyen

**Platform** M2.3.4

**Date:** 29-Apr-2020

**Situation**: There was a configuration error in Redis & Varnish settings that caused checkout issues making the checkout time much longer than expected for users due to excessive memory overload on checkout sessions.
Customers were able to add products in cart, proceed to checkout and clicked PLACE ORDER.

**ERROR EXPERIENCED**: Critical error when Paying by PayPal forever spinning wheel when paying via Card.

On investigation the payments were successful, sometimes numerous as they thought things failed and tried again. *All orders had Order numbers in the payment provider platform, eg PayPal, Adyen, Amazon Pay.*
However, these were not present in Magento. We would like to process these orders but there are not sufficient order details like product info (Colour-size/variant) present in the payment system.

For customers who waited for 3-4 mins for the page to complete and saw the success page, the orders were created successfully in Magento backend.

**Is there a way to complete the order and have it created in Magento 2 since it seems to already assign an order number to the transactions which are in Payment systems like PayPal and Adyen but no order present in Magento visible view?**

An example order number was 000046777

1. How can I get to create/complete these orders in Magento since Magento order numbers were already assigned?
2. Is it possible to see these orders in the database, if so, how?
3. If it is impossible to retrieve these orders from Magento or the DB, how can I create new orders manually and assign the *existing order numbers* that were captured/assigned by Magento in the payment system when the failure occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify (find by reserved order id in quote table) and convert programmatically the quote to  order which is failed 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108561/how-to-convert-a-quote-to-order